# Should "remove ads" in app purchase remove rewarded ads as well together with banners and interstitials?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, rewardedvideoad

This is mostly a Google Play and Apple Store policy question. I searched both site's help center but couldn't find an answer.

I have both rewarded video ads and banners/interstitial ads on my mobile game. Banners/interstitials can be removed by "remove ads" in app purchase at the time being. But I'm having difficulties to decide removing rewarded video ads with "remove ads" in app purchase. Because rewarded video ads are not implemented in an intrusive way like banners/interstitials. A player can play the game without seeing a single rewarded video. Seeing a rewarded video is totally player's choice and it gives game currency which enhances the player's experience. So if it's not against Apple and Google policies I'm planning to keep rewarded video ads in the game even though player buys "remove ads" in app purchase.

Would be very happy to know if that's possible(also if that's a good idea) and if anyone knows about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I am contemplating on the same question at the moment. What did you decide and was that the good choice?

Comment: I have exactly the same reasoning as you, so I am inclined to not include the rewarded video ads in the 'remove ads' in app purchase

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely choose to add or not to add. But you need to say to the users that "Hey! I'm gonna remove just banner and interstitial ads, not Ads that show up when you want to buy coin"
Most of the games do such like this. Hope it helps.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.